# Ubuntu Mate Main Menu: Automatically Added Menu

Tags: mate, menu

I adapted Main Menu in Ubuntu Mate to my needs. Suddenly a new menu was added automatically called "Collection" (after having started Thunderbird). I would like to delete that - but cannot find the this menu in "Main Menu"-Programme. Does anybody know why this Menu was added automatically, and how I can delete it?
Bül

Comment: Mate : Right click panel / panel items : Icons in the panels can be removed with "Remove From Panel" ..... and "+ Add to Panel" offers three different Menu´s .

Comment: Dear Knud!  Thank you for the answer, but sorry:  I did not mean a panel item, I meant an automatically added Menu Category in the Main Menu. I already found an answer here: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-remove-collection-menu-category-entry/24616/2     or: mkdir -p /home/$USER/.local/share/desktop-directories/
cat <<EOF > /home/$USER/.local/share/desktop-directories/mate-collection.directory
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Collection
Comment=The most frequently used shortcuts
Icon=starred
Type=Directory
NoDisplay=true
EOF

Answer (score 0):

The Collection is a new feature of [MATE 1.26](https://mate-desktop.org/blog/2021-08-08-mate-1-26-released/) which will be shipped in Ubuntu MATE 21.10 and maybe installed on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS and 21.04 using [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/fresh-mate).
Requests to make it configurable were already filed as https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-menus/issues/101 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mate-menus/+bug/1941942 .

Temporarily way to remove Collection menu category is to run the following [long command](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-menus/issues/101#issuecomment-907591259) (copy and paste whole code to the terminal in one shot):

```
mkdir -p /home/$USER/.local/share/desktop-directories/
cat <<EOF > /home/$USER/.local/share/desktop-directories/mate-collection.directory
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Collection
Comment=The most frequently used shortcuts
Icon=starred
Type=Directory
NoDisplay=true
EOF
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Thank you - already found this answer, too

Comment: You compare the nicknames, and then accept answer here too :)